# How to flatten deeply nested JSON in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a fairly nested JSON with sentiment measures for different "products". I would like to have this data load into a Pandas dataframe, so that I have the:

- product name
- language
- sentiment
- platform
- started date
- ended date
- value

stored in separate columns.

**Note**: all the product names in the complete data payload will be different.
The snippet here shows sentiments measures for '**engagement**', expect there to be other types of sentiments here (*StackOverFlow wouldn't allow me to include more sample data*).

```
{
    "product_ABC": {
        "en": {
            "engagement": {
                "Twitch": {
                    "series": [
                        {
                            "started_at": "2021-10-05 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "ended_at": "2021-10-06 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "value": 17274
                        },
                        {
                            "started_at": "2021-10-06 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "ended_at": "2021-10-07 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "value": 11354
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Youtube": {
                    "series": [
                        {
                            "started_at": "2021-10-05 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "ended_at": "2021-10-06 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "value": 76
                        },
                        {
                            "started_at": "2021-10-06 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "ended_at": "2021-10-07 00:00:00 -0700",
                            "value": 28
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that I can have a dataframe that resembles ...
[flattened tabular structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGR69.png)

Comment: show us what have you done and how the output should look like?

Comment: tried `pd.json_normalize`, but couldn't make any decent progress after several hours reading online examples

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but have a look at ‘wildpath’: https://pypi.org/project/wildpath/

Answer (score 0):

I found **flactdict** package, which flattened the payload, once loaded into a dictionary

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).